# Failure on Sending Form by Bootstrap Modal (POST)

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap modal dialog to display a form depending on what user does. If user clicks on new, form suppose to allow user to add new data, if edit, then it needs to query the DB and get results for that specific entry and allow user to edit, if view, query the DB just display the results.

I can't get first part of the code work. It is suppose to send the PHP as data to the PHP file and return back a message, but it's failing to do that as well. When I click save, nothing happens.

How can I make sure when I click submit it sends the data to the test.php and returns back a message?

Script

```
<script>
    // Form Text Correction
    function form(task) {
        var task = task;
        $("#task").text(task);
        $("#action").val(task);
    }
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var company = $("#company").val();
     if(company=='')
     {
         alert("Please enter UserId");
     }
     else{
        $.post("test.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           { // Data Sending With Request To Server
              company:company,
           },
     function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
         $("#result").html(response);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
         $("#form")[0].reset();
      });
    }
    });
</script>
```

Form

```
<a id="create-user" class="btn btn-primary add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDialog" href="#" title="Add" onClick="form('Add')"></a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDialog" class="edit" href="#" title="Edit" onClick="form('Edit')"></a>
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalDialog" class="view" href="#" title="View" onClick="form('View')"></a>
<div class="modal" id="ModalDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="Label"><span id="task"></span> a Vendor</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form name="VendorForm" id="VendorForm" action="/functions/updateVendor.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="">
            <fieldset>
                <div id="modalLeft" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="company" class="col-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <input type="text" name="company" class="form-control" id="company">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="contact" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact</label>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <input type="text" name="contact" class="form-control" id="contact">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="contactTitle" class="col-2 col-form-label">Contact Title</label>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <input type="text" name="contactTitle" class="form-control" id="contactTitle">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="notes">Brief Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="25" id="briefDescription"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="modalRight" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="workNumber" class="col-2 col-form-label">Work Number</label>
                      <div class="col-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" id="workNumber">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="mobileNumber" class="col-2 col-form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                      <div class="col-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="(xxx) xxx-xxxx" id="mobileNumber">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="email" class="col-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                        <div class="col-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="you@example.com" id="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="25" id="notes"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button id="save" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div id="result"></div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test.php

```
<?php
   if($_POST["company"])
   {
        $user = $_POST["company"];
       // Here, you can also perform some database query operations with above values.
       echo "Your user id is: ". $company;
  }

?>
```

Comment: how does it "fail", exactly? error messages? HTTP codes? Incorrect data? We need some debugging info to give us a clue. "not working" doesn't really explain the precise nature of the problem.

Comment: When I click Save, nothing happens. I wrote a form submit function that didn't help either, still nothing happened.

Comment: Your save button should be given type="submit" or give it onClick event to call any function. that will help

Comment: Submit didn't work because then PHP function got in the way and took the form elsewhere. I kept it button but added onClick="save()" and changed that to function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer I came up with

**PHP**

```
<?php
   if($_POST["company"])
   {
        $company = $_POST["company"];
       // Here, you can also perform some database query operations with above values.
       echo "Your user id is: ". $company;
  }

?>
```

**HTML & jQuery**

```
<script>
    // Form Text Correction
    function form(task) {
        var task = task;
        $("#task").text(task);
        $("#action").val(task);
    }
    function save(){
        var company = $("#company").val();
     if(company=='')
     {
         alert("Please enter UserId");
     }
     else{
        $.post("test.php", //Required URL of the page on server
           { // Data Sending With Request To Server
              company:company,
           },
     function(response,status){ // Required Callback Function
         $("#result").html(response);//"response" receives - whatever written in echo of above PHP script.
         // $("#form")[0].reset();
      });
    }
    };

</script>
<button type="button" onClick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

Comment: `$("#save").click(function(){` should have been already doing that without the need for retro inline event handlers. The only reason it wouldn't is if the modal is only rendered to the page after the ``$("#save").click(function(){` was declared. In which case `$(document).on("click", "#save", function(event) {` would solve it, using delegated events. A bit neater than inline event handlers. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ under the section "Direct and delegated events" for more detail.